# How to show uniq category with filter

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, angularjs

I am displaying list of categories from JSON file using Angular.js.
But it is showing duplicate categories but I want to filter out the duplicate categories and show uniq categories. Also I want if user clicks on any category then it should show the post name based on selected category for example if user selects "aframax" then it should show post title "Article22". Please see my code here "http://plnkr.co/edit/1vcIAPSwvxQcbIzMhyzp?p=preview"

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are looking for is 'group by' for ng-repeat. Perhaps a better solution is to restructure the JSON where each category contains a list of posts, rather than each post containing a list of categories.

If you rather not change the JSON, minor tweaks to the logic are necessary to get the effect you are looking for. Here is an update plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0pXRSd8k9yiq8Y6314xo?p=preview

Instead of pushing all categories (including duplicates) into an array, create a map that will hold each individual category by id, and an array that references posts in that category. When encountering a unique category while looping though the posts, add it to the map. Then add the post to that category.

Finally in the html, add a nested ng-repeat for the posts. Use a ng-show to show/hide the posts underneath each category

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am actually new in Angular.JS. I really appreciate your help here. What I want is to show only parent categories first (I have to check if category's parent:0) and show all the posts and then clicking on the category will show the posts based on the selected category and then show sub category (I am not sure how would I show sub category) then clicking on sub category will show the posts based on sub category. I will really appreciate if you can just show me the way to achieve that. same link "http://plnkr.co/edit/1vcIAPSwvxQcbIzMhyzp?p=preview"